# Flutter: Using texture from flutter_webrtc for image processing in firebase_ml_vision

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webrtc, firebase-mlkit

We're using the [flutter_webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc) package to make peer-to-peer video calls. However we need to do some image processing on the camera image using [firebase_ml_vision](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_ml_vision). There are lots of examples on how to use firebase_ml_vision together with the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package.

The problem is that the camera and flutter_webrtc packages can't be used together, since the camera resource can only be accessed once.
There would be no problem by using only flutter_webrtc, but the only way to access the camera image is by grabbing a textureID which we're not able to convert to an image suitable for firebase.

Question:
How can we extract the bytes from the texture provided by flutter_webrtc?

Any other suggestions or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, collaborator of flutter_webrtc plugin here. You can't extract bytes from texture, afaik, even if it's possible, that would introduce noticable performance overhead). You have to go deeper, modify java-part source, implement your own `VideoSink` and feed video frames to Firebase ML. And all that will require a LOT of work. The only thing I can help you is attaching your implementation `VideoSink`

Comment: Hello Dima, I've opened an issue on the repository and got an answer - however I did not get it going because I don't have too much knowledge in Flutter yet... Do you think this is feasible? https://github.com/cloudwebrtc/flutter-webrtc/issues/108